# Loading local html with $.load

Tags: android, jquery, android-webview

In my app, am loading a local html which is residing in SD card as

```
String extPath = getExternalFilesDir(null).toString();
String html = getHtml(extPath+File.separator+fileName); //it just reads html file and returns content as string
webvu.loadDataWithBaseURL("file://"+extPath+File.separator,html ,
"text/html","UTF-8", null);
```

the html file loaded in the web view (webvu) tries to load another html file with $.load ajax call

> $.load("base.html",function(){ ... });

ajax load is throwing the below error. How can I resolve this

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.sdcardwebview/files/sec.html.
>   Cannot make any requests from null. at null:1

Comment: SD Cards are mounted, so the path you are addressing is probably an alias to another location (/mounts/SD_CARD_NAME). Also AJAX is not allowed to operate outside it's domain. When you enter the mount's path, even through the alias, it's probably not part of the standard "file://" protocol (thus domain).

Comment: @Allendar, Thanks, but webvu.loadDataWithBaseURL("file://"+extPath+File.separator,html ,
"text/html","UTF-8", null); is picking the initial html properly! if mount path is not part of "file://" protocol then even that should fail right ? ... Is there any other alternative to overcome same origin error ?

Comment: True, you could test the 4th parameter (NULL) with "about:blank" and see if you get a valid fallback. I think it wants todo something with the NULL if if the function encounters a fetch error. As NULL is nothing, it can't do anything with it. You can also try getExternalStorageDirectory() or getExternalFilesDir() with nu NULL given.

Comment: @Allendar, Tried with different values for historyUrl (4th parameter), was not of much help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally figured out the solution

The null origin issue happens only in JB, which supposedly has a webview based on new webkit which implements stricter same origin policy.

Hence the code in question works perfectly fine on all version of android below JB. To get the code work on JB, all we need to do is change web view settings. Just call

```
webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
```

Comment: your solution is only valid for api 16+

Comment: maybe i did something wrong but this didnt work on my kk device.